# Ошибка с getchar()

Tags: c, ввод

***code.c***:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_WORD_LENGHT 128

typedef struct Node {
    char *word;             // Слово
    int cnt;                // Кол-во данных слов
    struct Node *next;      // Указатель на следующий элемент стека
} Node;


int increase ( Node *head, char *word )
{
    Node *x = head;
    do {
        if ( strcmp((x->word), word) == 0 )
        {
            x->cnt++;
            return 1;
        }
        x = x->next;
    } while ( x->next != NULL );
    return 0;
}


void push ( Node **head, char *word_link )
{
    Node *tmp;

    if ( ( tmp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node)) ) == NULL )
    {
        printf("Malloc function error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    tmp->word = word_link;
    tmp->cnt = 1;
    tmp->next = *head;

    *head = tmp;
}


int reader ( char word[MAX_WORD_LENGHT], int *letter_count )
{
    char c;
    *letter_count = 0;
    while ( (c = getchar()) != ( EOF || ' ' || '\t' || '\n' ) )
    {
        printf("%d\n", *letter_count);              // Для отладки
        if ( *letter_count >= MAX_WORD_LENGHT )
        {
            printf("Word lenght exceeded.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        word[*letter_count] = c;
        *letter_count += 1;
    }
    if ( c != EOF )
    {
        word[*letter_count] = '\0';
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


void malloc_it ( char *word_link, char word[MAX_WORD_LENGHT], int letter_count )
{
    if ( (word_link = (char*) malloc(letter_count)) == NULL )
    {
        printf("Malloc function error.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(word_link, word);
}


int main ( void )
{
    Node *head = NULL;
    char word[MAX_WORD_LENGHT];
    char *word_link;
    int letter_count;

    while ( reader(word, &letter_count) != 0 )
    {
        if ( !(increase(head, word)) )
        {
            malloc_it(word_link, word, letter_count);
            push(&head, word_link);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Планировалось организовать считывание слов со стандартного ввода и помещение их в стек если они появились первый раз, если же они уже встречались до этого - увеличить счетчик. ( не доделано ).

```
user@user:~$ cc code.c
user@user:~$ ./a.out
a
0
1
bc
2
3
4
def
5
6
7
8
CTRL+D
9
10
11
12
...
127
128
Word lenght exceeded.
```

Почему это происходит?
Не обнуляется переменная для подсчета длины слова после ввода пробельного символа как ожидалось, а после нажатия ***CTRL+D*** происходит увеличение этой переменной до максимального значения и выход из программы.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте посмотрим, как же работает

```
(c = getchar()) != ( EOF || ' ' || '\t' || '\n' )
```

Вы считываете значение типа `int`, преобразуете его в `char` и записываете в `c`, каковое затем сравнивается с результатом применения операции **логического** (не побитового) **или** к значениям `EOF` и так далее, которые все ненулевые, а значит, рассматриваются как `true`, т.е. в результате вы сравниваете `c` с единицей.

Все остальное я и не рассматривал...

Так что вам надо переписать ваше сравнение правильно — как или для сравнений `c` с конкретным символом. Только учтите, что если `c` — `char`, то сравнение с `EOF` может сработать неверно — например, при чтении символа с кодом -1 (0xFF, в зависимости от знаковости/беззнаковости `char` в вашей реализации).

`EOF` для того и есть значение `int` (обычно -1, не помню, кажется, в стандарте не говорится, что именно -1, но дело не в этом — главное, что `EOF` не может совпадать ни с одним считанным значением `char`). Потому `getchar` и возвращает `int`, а не `char`, так что советую подумать над изменением типа `c`.